# Cursor in Android Studio testing and returning values

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, cursor

I am stuck with sqlite and need help.

I have already a table in my sqlite database with some information stored in it. The user of the application is supposed to be guessing what is stored in the specific table which i choose. In my table i have 2 columns, the first column is ID and the second is NAME.

This is my code so far:

public boolean insertData(String name) {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] cols = new String[]{COL_1, COL_2};

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, cols, COL_2 + "=?", new String[]{"" + name}, null, null, null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}
```

This code is only returning true or false depending on the position of the cursor.

My question is: How can I return the specific ID of the first column when the user has guessed right on the NAME in column 2.

For example we have the name ALEX in column 2, with the ID of 3.

I type ALEX and i get the return value of the ID, which is 3.

Comment: what if two rows have NAME = "ALEX"? what do you really need that ID for?

Comment: The database is pre defined by me. Every row is unique, there is not 2 Alex only 1 Alex and he is unique. I need the ID for later development in the application, to be able to know what the ID is of the answer on the first question, so after 5-6 questions I can see if the users of the application have unique answers or identical.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
//make global
    Cursor c;  
    int id = 0;
    onCreate(){
       if(insertData("name")){
           if(id > 0){
              //do something
           }
       }
    }
    public boolean insertData(String name) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] cols = new String[]{COL_1, COL_2};

        c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, cols, COL_2 + "=?", new String[]{"" + name}, null, null, null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            return false;
        } else{
             if(c.moveToFirst()){
                id = Integer.parsInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")))
             }
             return true;
        }
    }
```